# how to get value of column in datgrid using asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net, sql, c#-4.0, datagrid

here is code which is working. it is in loop  which is deleting last row of data in grid but some how i am not able to pick the single row value for deleting particular selected row in Datagrid.

```
enter code here
    String Name1;
protected void DataGrid1_DeleteCommand(object source, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridItem dataGridItem;

    foreach (DataGridItem dataGridItem in DataGrid1.Items)
    {
        String Name = dataGridItem.Cells[2].Text;
        Label1.Text = Name;
        Name1=Name;
    }
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from salaryentry where levelnno='" + Name1 + "'", con);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    databind();

}
```

Comment: Even if english is not your native language you could show search effort, show what you've tried and what didn't work. Have a look here for more tips how to improve your questions: [tinyurl.com/so-hints](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints).

Comment: Could you possibly provide code? Maybe that will provide a better question that what you wrote :/

Comment: here is code which is working. it is in loop  which is deleting last row of data in grid but some how i am not able to pick the single row value for deleting particular selected row in grid.                        String Name1;
    protected void DataGrid1_DeleteCommand(object source, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridItem dataGridItem;
      
        foreach (DataGridItem dataGridItem in DataGrid1.Items)
        {
            String Name = dataGridItem.Cells[2].Text;
            Label1.Text = Name;
            Name1=Name;
        }
        ;
        ..

Comment: guys found solution here it is

Answer (score 2):

use this to select row and print into text box and using delete command to delete the row:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = dataGridView1[0, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
}
```